# Role of low carbohydrate diet and urine alkalinization, in treatment of fungal chronic prostatitis

Tags: fungal-infection, prostate, prostatitis, yeast-infection

[Chronic prostatitis/chronic pelvic pain syndrome: the role of an antifungal regimen:](http://ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3936149/)

> MATERIAL AND METHODS:
>   We included 1,000 consecutive patients. The inclusion criteria included failure of response to four consecutive weeks of antibiotic and alpha-blockers. The antifungal regimen was continued for two weeks. It included a **low carbohydrate diet**, the **alkalinization of urine**, and administration of fluconazole.

What is the reasoning behind low carbohydrate diet and urine alkalinization?